# iCloud - Moving the file completed

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, nsfilemanager, icloud

I can able to move a file from the local directory to iCloud using the condition `setUbiquitous:YES`. The file has been moved successfully. If the file size is large, it takes certain time to complete moving. Is there any method to identify, if the file has completed moving to iCloud? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Can you help me to move an image file from local directory to icloud with source codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: I haven't done this myself, so all the info below is purely from reading the documentation:

The `NSMetadataItem` class has, among others, an attribute key called `NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey`. Knowing this, you should be able to set up an `NSMetadataQuery` that notifies you once the item has been uploaded.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you have any idea how to use NSMetadataUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey? Any sample code?

Answer (score 3):

You can check with NSUURL getResourceValue:forKey:error: method

NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadedKey—Indicates that locally made changes were successfully uploaded to the iCloud server.

NSURLUbiquitousItemIsUploadingKey—Indicates that locally made changes are being uploaded to the iCloud server now.

NSURLUbiquitousItemPercentUploadedKey—For an item being uploaded, indicates what percentage of the changes have already been uploaded to the server.

For details: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1